# Why do orc files consume more space than parquet files in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet, orc

As far as I understand, ORC files are supposed to be smaller and more compressed than parquet files. However, when I populate my orc table in Apache Hive by selecting rows from my parquet table, the orc table ends up consuming about 7 times more disk space.

Any ideas why this happens? My table schema is as follows. It contains a length 200000 array of integers 0, 1 and 2 and each partition has about 10000 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE orc_table (
  field1 STRING
, field2 INT
, field3 STRING
, field4 STRING
, array_field ARRAY < INT >
) PARTITIONED BY (
    partition_name STRING
);

ALTER TABLE orc_table ADD PARTITION (partition_name='<partition-name>');

ALTER TABLE orc_table PARTITION (partition_name='<partition_name>') SET FILEFORMAT ORC;

INSERT INTO TABLE orc_table PARTITION (partition_name='<partition_name>')
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, array_field FROM parquet_table
WHERE partition_name='<partition_name>';
```

Comment: BTW You didn't configure compression settings: switch on compression and compression codec, etc.

Comment: @leftjoin I didn't configure compression settings as I thought they have default values as described here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

Should I specify them in the query?

Comment: Better check it with compression configured. And there are also other ORC parameters like indexes(i believe they enabled  by default) and Bloom filters which may consume additional space. There are no indexes in parquet. I didn't check it all myself and that is why I cannot answer for sure.

Comment: Ok, I found the reason this happens: For some reason, my orc-files are plaintext, i.e. not compressed. It seems that the default orc settings only apply to tables that aren't partitioned. And if I set them manually for the partitioned table, it still has no effect. So apparently, I have to set the compression settings for each partition separately. I have no idea, how to do that, however. At least this is not a valid query:
`alter table orc_table partition (partition_name='<partition_name>') set tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing these settings solved the problem:

```
SET hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
```

Appearently, Hive uses map-reduce for converting between the data formats. Therefore, also map-reduce output compression needs to be switched on. But this is only guess.